# Merit no target found on a #create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, merit-gem

I'm trying to set a badge_rule for a first create action named "Selection" (product selection by members).

The rule :

## app/models/merit/badge_rules.rb

```
grant_on 'member/selections#create',  badge: 'FirstSelection', to: :member do |selection|
   selection.member.selections.count == 1
end
```

The controller "Selections" is in the folder "member" : *controllers/member/selections_controller.rb*

At the #create action, here's my error report :

> Merit::Action Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "merit_actions".* FROM "merit_actions" WHERE "merit_actions"."processed" = $1  [["processed", "f"]]
>      (0.2ms)  BEGIN
>     SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "merit_actions" SET "processed" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "merit_actions"."id" = $3  [["processed", "t"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-07 09:35:24.776028"], ["id", 30]]
>      (0.5ms)  COMMIT
>   [merit] no target found: uninitialized constant Member::Selection. /Users/youguild/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/merit-3.0.1/lib/merit/base_target_finder.rb:13:in `find'
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 211ms (Views: 2.8ms | ActiveRecord: 134.4ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `member' for true:TrueClass):
>
> app/models/merit/badge_rules.rb:53:in `block in initialize'

Why is the error happening and how can I resolve it?

## EDIT

This problem was solved by :

1. Add the Model name on the grant_on : model_name: 'Selection' *(in the case)*
2. Check that the instance variable is with " @ ". Was 'selection = Selection.new(selection_params) ' => ' @selection = Selection.new(selection_params) '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's translating the controller name into the model name, but the controller is namespaced with `Member`. Try adding the option `model_name: "Selection"` to your `grant_on` line.

Comment: Hi @TuteC, it's returns me now : " [merit] no target_obj found on Rule#applies? "... My research shows that it's rendering a boolean field... For information, the Create action on SelectionController is made with React.js, and respond to "format.json" also. Thx.

Comment: Does that controller action contain an instance variable named `@selection` with the created instance?

Comment: It was the stupidest thing we can imagine : it was the lack of "@" in the create action that was the problem... Ex, it was : selection = Selection.new(selection_params), now its @selection = Sel... Thx so much!!